# Display value of choicefield of the tuple in template django

Tags: python, html, django

i have tuple

```
PRICES_DATES_SD_PRICES_CHOICES = (('SD-A', 'Option SD-A'), ('SD-B', 'Option SD-B'), ('SD-C', 'Option SD-C'))
```

and my model like this:

```
class PackagePricesAndDates(models.Model):`
      prices_SD = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PRICES_DATES_SD_PRICES_CHOICES)`
```

in the template when i loop in object_list :

```
{% for pricedate in object_list %}
<tr>
                    <td colspan=3 style="border-top:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) solid 1px;padding-top:17px;">
                        <table class="sub">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:50%">Prices SD</td>
                            <td>""""{{ pricedate.prices_SD }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Prices HD</td>
                            <td>""""{{ pricedate.prices_HD }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

the value of pricedate.prices_SD display the key not the value of tuple (the first value not the second) 
how can i get the second value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `{{ pricedate.get_prices_SD_display }}`

Syntax : `get_FIELDNAME_display()`

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: thank you i use it, it resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

It's because this line of code is returning key, not the value.

```
{{ pricedate.prices_SD }}
```

There's a method called [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) in Django which you can use. 
Try this instead..

```
{{pricedate.get_prices_SD_display}}
```